# MS access form field to display values of a cell as list

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way in ms access forms to make display values in a field in the same order as in the fiels? For example, I have dates that I contacted a patient as below:

In MS access forms when I click on the Date file I want the dates need to be opends as list dropdown in the same order it was entered. How could I achieve this. Any ideas, most welcome and thank you in advance!

```
Id Date:
01 13March2020, 15April2021, 16May2022
02 20May2016, 21June2017, 22Jul2018
```

Comment: Are those multiple dates in a single field as a comma-separated string? If so, VBA will have to parse the string and rebuild each element as an actual date value and add items to combobox set as Value List.

Comment: Yes it is multiple dates with single field as a comma sepatated string. Is there an example of the VBA code to refer. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency in structure is critical for parsing strings. This assumes Date field is text type with comma-separated string (not a multi-value field).

Combobox (or listbox) RowSourceType property must be set to ValueList. If form is bound to the sample data table, code references Date field in form's Current event. Code like:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim  aryD As Variant, x As Integer
Me.Combo0.RowSource = ""
If Not IsNull(Me.Date) Then
    aryD = Split(Me.Date, ",")
    For x = 0 To UBound(aryD)
        Me.Combo0.AddItem Trim(aryD(x))
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

BTW, should not use reserved words as names. **Date** is a reserved word.

Comment: Hi, the code works but somehow it shows the list of dates from all records. I want only each particular cell values as drop down list or just list. how can this be achieved? When contacted a customer the 1st contacted dated with be entered and 2nd contacted date and so on,... so the list on order will be visible the order of contacted dates.

Comment: I tested this code and it works for me. Lists only dates found in current record.